# onchange select option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

Guys here is my script to get value of selected option on change but not working as expected. on option change I want to get the value of the selected option but it returns all the previous and current value.Why so?

```
<div id="dropdown" style="height: 30px;width: 100%;text-align: center;">
Select website url:
<select name="selectsite"  id="selectsite" style="border-radius: 5px; width: 300px;">
            <option value="0">site1</option>
            <option value="1">site2</option>
            <option value="2">site3</option>
</select>
</div>
<br />
<button id="start" type="button">Start</button>
<button id="pause" type="button">Pause</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

  var selectval = $('#selectsite').val(); //get value of select option

 //when first option is selected which is by default
  if(selectval == 0) {
    var selval = 0;
    var injsArray = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>');
    var data = injsArray[selval]['dat']; //load the data
    $('#start').on('click',function(){
            playthis(selval, data); 
    });
  }

  $('#selectsite').on('change',function(e) {
   var selval = $(this).val();
   var injsArray = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>');
   var hdata = injsArray[selval]['dat']; //load the data

    $('#start').on('click',function(){
            playthis(selval,hdata); 
    });   
  });

  function playthis(value,data){
    console.log("Selected option value is "+value);
  }

});
</script>
```

How to solve this problem? Please suggest if I am doing something wrong since I am new to programming.
Thanks in advance

Comment: just put alert inside on change event , check its go inside that function or not

Comment: because you are registering multiple click handlers

Answer (score 4):

Every time the change handler is called you are registering a new click handler with a closure value `selval` that is the reason for the multiple calls.

You can only have one click handler which will fetch the current value of the `select` and call `playthis` as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#start').on('click', function () {
        playthis($('#selectsite').val());
    });

    function playthis(value) {
        console.log("Selected option value is " + value);
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4nu8cqse/)

Another option will be is to unbind the previous handlers which I wouldn't recommend if possible.

---

Based on the update try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var injsArray = $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>');
    $('#start').on('click', function () {
        var selval = $('#selectsite').val();
        var hdata = injsArray[selval]['dat']; //load the data
        playthis(selval, hdata);
    });

    function playthis(value, data) {
        console.log("Selected option value is " + value);
    }

});
```

Comment: but I need to check if its first option which is by default or the next options

Comment: @RonitAdhikari There is exactly no difference in the code you posted about the default.

Comment: @RonitAdhikari what do you mean?

Comment: @ArunPJohny actually I am sending json data as second parameter in playthis function so by the solution you provided it works fine but if I have to send data which is on the basis of selected option How can I achieve that ??

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more clear....data is also passed as second parameter

Comment: unbinding the previous click handlers worked for me. thanks @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it will work

```
$('#selectsite').change(function(e) { 
   var selval = $(this).val();
   $('#start').click(function(){
       playthis(selval); 
   }); 
);
```

Comment: Your answer will have same exact issue and click(...) is the same exact thing as on("click",...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this

getting the selected value on click of start

you can check the demo here

http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/3xgLjdew/

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#start').click(function(){
        var a = $("#selectsite").val()
        alert(a);

        if(a == 0){
            alert("do this")
        }
        else if(a == 1){
            alert("do that")
        }
        else if(a == 2){
           alert("do other")
        }
    })

});
```